# Magento session doesn't get updated in event observer

Tags: php, magento

I set a session variable through ajax request like in checkout page

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->setMyValue($value_from_post_data);
```

The above is set in a controller of a custom module.

I have an event observer which observes checkout_onepage_controller_success_action here, when I access the session, I don't find my_value the session variable I created.

Note:
The session ids are same. No change in them. After the session value is set, I printed the whole session data to confirm, the setMyValue created my_value in the session.

So the ajax request has done its job. It has set the variable 
But the observer picks up old session data. Why is this happening, give me a work around

Is this a bug in magento? Is there a method with which I can ask magento to refresh the session object. Something like say for example

```
Mage::getModel('core/session')->pleaseMagentoRefreshSessionObject();
```

So that I get the new session object in the memory.

Comment: Can you also show the code where you are getting the session data in the observer ?

Comment: As usual, $data = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getMyValue(); The code is proprietary. Event name is checkout_onepage_controller_success. This is where the I get the session value. the session ids are the same. The session variables are the same. its just that particular variable that is missing

Comment: The wisest thing I can suggest is to set and get the session variable using the standard PHP way ( $_SESSION ) in order to determine whether it has something to do with using the Magento's Singleton

Comment: @jevgeni Bogatyrjov : I ve tried it already. The same thing happens.. The session gets created but doesn't update

Comment: Have you tried adding session_write_close(); after setting the value to session?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sounds like a **session write lock**.
For some reason, somewhere Magento (or ZF/PHP) closes the session. If you have configured your store to save the session in the file system, it gets a write lock.

This is because in that state the server can send the session to the network socket because it knows that is won't be re/overwritten. In this state the session still exists in memory and you can stil read and write to the session object but it won't get saved to the file system. So on a new request you lose the data that is write after the write lock, exactly what happens in your situation.

A very simple workaround is to save the sessions in the database. To do that, edit your "app/etc/local.xml" and replace:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>
```

For:

```
<session_save><![CDATA[db]]></session_save>
```

(After that clear al the files in "var/session" and "var/cache")

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you could try here.

**1.)** Your session save path is not be writeable by the server, meaning it will be regenerated for every request. You can test this with a small script that checks if your `session_save_path` is writeable:

```
<?php
    if ( !is_writable(session_save_path()) ) {
        echo 'Whoops, the session save path at "'.session_save_path().'" is NOT writable!';
    } else {
        echo 'The session save path at "'.session_save_path().'" IS writable, look elsewhere!';
    }
?>
```

Obviously once you know the answer you can take necessary steps based on your server/platform. The most common solution is to set the `session.save_path = "/tmp"` in the `php.ini` and restart apache.

**2.)** Something has gone very wrong in your `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Session/Abstract/Varien.php` file. Get a clean version from a fresh download **of your Magento version**.

**3.)** Your AJAX requests are being redirected to `https://` instead of `http://`. Follow the request with the Web Inspector (or equivalent) and look for 302 redirects. If you get them, keep going down this list.

**4.)** Your AJAX request does not include the data parameter that Magento is expecting, namely `isAjax`:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'isAjax': true }, // <-- set this value
    url: '//' + document.location.hostname + '/index.php/module/controller/method/',
    method: 'POST'
})
.done(function( json ) {
    var data = eval(json);
    jQuery('#div').html( data.content );
});
```

**5.)** More of the same: you don't have a *form_key* defined for your AJAX request. This is required to validate the request.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { 'form_key': window.FORM_KEY, 'isAjax': true }, // <-- note the form_key
    url: '//' + document.location.hostname + '/index.php/module/controller/method/',
    method: 'POST'
})
.done(function( json ) {
    var data = eval(json);
    jQuery('#div').html( data.content );
});
```

The global javascript object `window.FORM_KEY` is made available by the Magento JS and it is accessible site-wide.

---

Happy hunting!